# is it possible to do batch updates to the clickhouse using clickhouse-jdbc driver?

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc, clickhouse

I'm trying to do a batch update of data to one of the tables in clickhouse database. I use such driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.clickhouse</groupId>
    <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.52</version>
</dependency>
```

The thing is when i update a table using next instruction:

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(str)
```

I have an empty array as a response and there's no records in the database. There's no exceptions also.

Does it mean that the driver is not ready for batch updates? Is there any workarounds?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Clickhouse jdbc driver support batch updates. In plain jdbc code this will look like this:

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

            for (Data data : datas) {
                ps.setInt(1, data.id);
                ps.addBatch();
            }

            ps.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like batch update method cannot support inserting clickhouse array column.